# Accessing the Stack Exchange API not on behalf of an user?

Tags: support, authentication

I'm implementing an App and intend to use Stack Exchange tags to classify content, of course, respecting the [terms of use](https://stackexchange.com/legal/api-terms-of-use).

However, the [Authentication documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) says I'd need to use the OAuth 2.0 workflow, which requires the user to be redirected to Stackoverflow, which doesn't make sense because my app is not acting in behalf of any user. I just wanted to pass in my `client_id`, `secret` and `access_token` and get the data I need, respecting the quota.

[RankOverflow](https://stackapps.com/questions/7661/rankoverflow-a-website-to-calculate-your-stack-overflow-reputation-rank-in-all) seems to have the same use case as I do, so I believe it's possible.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I don't use the API. I just get the website over PHP and parse it with jQuery to get my required data. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to use OAuth if you are trying to add or modify data (including votes).  If you want to do that, your app must log in as a user, no exceptions.

If you just want to read or search data, don't bother with OAuth (or an `access_token`).

Reference:

- [Is it okay to just send the API key (without implementing oauth-2 login)?](https://stackapps.com/questions/7332/is-it-okay-to-just-send-the-api-key-without-implementing-oauth-2-login)
- [How to increase app request quota from 300 to 10,000?](https://stackapps.com/questions/6961/how-to-increase-app-request-quota-from-300-to-10-000)
- [Looking for a beginner's tutorial to using the API](https://stackapps.com/questions/4511/looking-for-a-beginners-tutorial-to-using-the-api)

Comment: Thanks. The secret was to pass the `key={key}` as a query parameter to increase the quota to 10k.